# How to handle varchar(max) in t4 script?

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, t4, varcharmax

I'm using .tt scripting in VS 2017(SSDT 2017) in the DB project. We create staging tables structures manually and then the T4 script generates final destination tables based on the staging table structure.

I have this code to get columns and their data types to create my final destination tables but it looks if one of the fields is defined as varchar(max) then generated field gets varchar data type and that is it.
Here is the sample of the script.

```
         foreach (var col in table.GetReferenced(Table.Columns))
        {

            string columnText;
            string columnName = col.Name.Parts[2];

            // this attempts to limit to only columns from the source. there's gotta be a cleaner way.
            if (!skipColumns.Contains(columnName))
            {

                int length = col.GetProperty<int>(Column.Length);
                int precision = col.GetProperty<int>(Column.Precision);
                int scale = col.GetProperty<int>(Column.Scale);

                string suffix;
                if (length != 0)
                {
                    suffix = String.Format("({0})", length);
                }
                else if (precision != 0)
                {
                    suffix = String.Format("({0},{1})", precision, scale);
                }
                else if (precision == 0 && scale != 0)
                {
                    suffix = String.Format("({0})", scale);
                }
                else
                {
                    suffix = "";
                }

                bool nullable = col.GetProperty<bool>(Column.Nullable);
                string nullText = nullable ? "NULL" : "NOT NULL";

                string dataType = col.GetReferenced(Column.DataType).FirstOrDefault().Name.ToString();

                columnText = String.Format("[{0}] {1}{2} {3}", columnName, dataType, suffix, nullText);

                WriteLine("         " + columnText + ",");
            }
        }
```

How to handle varchar(max) in t4 script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the answer. 
You would have to use the following and then compare it.

```
    bool isMax = col.GetProperty<bool>(Column.IsMax);
...
  if (isMax) 
                    {
                        suffix = String.Format("({0})", "max");
                    }
```